# Adding a place with google places api using jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-places-api

When I try to add a place to Google Places I get an error:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Heres my code:

HTML:

```
<form id="addShopForm">

          ...

        <a type="submit" id="submitshop">Submit</a>

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#submitshop').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true&key=asdEFasdBaasdasdasdMrN2ST5tRS5c",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: {
                       "location": {
                        "lat": 68.7425471,
                        "lng": 9.1370879
                       },
                       "accuracy": 50,
                       "name": "Test Shop!",
                       "language": "de"
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                    },
                    error: function (errormessage) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(errormessage));
                        //{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
                    }
                });
});
```

Comment: Is it even possible to add places via jQuery.ajax() ? Could you give me an alternative solution using something else?

Comment: Can't help if you don't post the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling to get this to work. After executing your code, I noticed this error in my chrome debugger:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key={Key}
Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control Allow-Origin. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&{key}
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key={Key}. 
Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So it seems as though the google maps places API does not support cross domain, even though you have specified it in the ajax object.

Fortunately, there is a [client-side javascript library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). Unfortunately, it does not support adding places or events :(.

I hope google add more support for the places API in the future.